# Bars around side of div, firefox only

Tags: css, firefox

I am seeing bars one the left and right side of a div unexpectedly and only on Firefox.

[image: Strange side bars]

The code that creates the banner is:

```
.ribbon {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    border: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #757575;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: -46px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 110px;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    size: 11px;
}
.ribbon .txt {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -18px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The text is in a div that has the class `txt` and is wrapped in the div with the class `ribbon`. Any reason why this is only visible in Firefox?

I used this [codepen with just position modifications](https://codepen.io/gilluminate/pen/jusoI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do that will avoid you that issue:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  position: relative;
}

.ribbon {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(50%, -100%);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  background: #757575;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  right: 0;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  z-index: 0;
}

.ribbon:before,
.ribbon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}

.ribbon:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="ribbon">
    Example Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does seem to not have the bars around it, I am assuming it is due to no extra div. If I wanted to have the in the top left corner, do I just change the transform origins? Also how would I make the angle change of the ends to be in the top left? I am marking this as accepted as it is correct.

Comment: @Fireynis it's not because of the div but because I made the pseudo element to overflow behind the main element (you can add a transparent background on the main element to notice this) ... to change the angle, you to consider the skewX, so intead of 45deg you make -45deg and also change the origin to make it top instead of bottom (you keep the left/right for each pseudo element)